# How to define selectId for entity adapter when the relevant id is defined on the backend?

Tags: angular, api, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I'm dispatching the upsert action/ reducer on my store to add a new record to state and there is an effect that will call the backend and add the record/ document to my mongodb instance.

Given that the only sensible id for this particular model is defined by my backend logic at the time of document creation, how should i define selectId in my entity implementation in my front end?

At the moment an item is added to state with `id: undefined` and i get the warning:

> entity.js:76 @ngrx/entity: The entity passed to the `selectId`
>   implementation returned undefined. You should probably provide your
>   own `selectId` implementation.

My adapter is defined as:

```
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<PublishedData> = createEntityAdapter<
  PublishedData
>({ selectId: (publishedData: PublishedData) => publishedData.doi });
```

and the relevant effect is:

```
@Effect()
  UpsertPublishedData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<UpsertPublishedData>(PublishedDataActionTypes.UpsertPublishedData),
    switchMap(action => this.publishedDataApi.create(action.payload.publishedData)
    .pipe(mergeMap((data: PublishedData) => [ new UpsertPublishedData({ publishedData: data }),
      this.publishedDataApi.register(data[0].doi)]),
    catchError(err => of(new FailedPublishedDataAction(err)))))
  );
```

`publishedData.doi` is the offending field that I need to use to reference the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have modified the reducer to not add the record to state on the first pass where the id field (doi) is undefined.

```
case PublishedDataActionTypes.UpsertWaitPublishedData: {
  if (action.payload.publishedData && action.payload.publishedData.doi) {
    return adapter.upsertOne(action.payload.publishedData, state);
  }
  return state;
}
```

from this originally:

```
  case PublishedDataActionTypes.UpsertPublishedData: {
      return adapter.upsertOne(action.payload.publishedData, state);
    }
```

This ensures the record in state matches that in the database. This approach is still in line with an entity approach whereby no additional `UpsertPublishedDataSuccess` action is required.

Comment: i feel like the adapter should handle this without a custom implementation

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I will consider 2 options:

- **Option 1: implement a pessimistic creation (to stay simple)**

When a new record is created by user, an action for instance `AddRecord` invokes a `POST` request to backend api. The successful response emits a new action `AddRecordSuccess` which add the new created record (with `id` sent by backend) into the store with `@ngrx/entity`.

During creation process (request to backend), a loader indicator should be displayed to notify user.

- **Option 2: implement a optimistic creation (for better UX)**

If optimistic update is really a need or an objective to reach, either a temporary or permanent `id` should be generated by front-end app :

- temporary `id` is used inside the store to manage entities to be synchronized. When entities are created by backend, the `id` should be updated or completed by a permanent backend `id`.
- permanent `id` could be generated by front-end (UUID for instance), and sent to 
  be used by backend.

In all the case, `@ngrx/entity` need an identifier (`number` or `string`) to identify and manage entities in store.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Neither of these options answer the question. They just state the question again in less detail.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your comment, I really tried to help by giving 2 options I will consider in such case. You need an identifier, you can't leave undefined. Maybe you should give more explanations or more details on your expectations.

Comment: Option 1 could solve the problem because entity is added after backend response (so with an id). But I understand that pessimistic creation could not be an option regarding your UX specs.

Comment: If you had implemented entity you would know that the same action is used for triggering effects as well as modifying the state so there is no "AddRecordSuccess" action

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ngrx/entity, just specifiy a selectId method when creating your EntityAdapter.
 [see for more info: createentityadapter](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/entity/adapter.md#createentityadapter)

```
 dexport const adapter: EntityAdapter<Location > = createEntityAdapter<Location>({
  selectId: (location: Location) => location.locationid,
});
```